# Proposal for an Applied math/Math modeling stackexchange needs 31 more question titles

Tags: discussion, area51

There is currently a proposal going on for an applied math/math modeling SE (at http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/57490/mathematical-modeling). Such proposals need 2 things to go forward: 60 `followers' and 40`good question titles'. Anyone can ask up to 5 questions and vote on 5 others; a `good question' is one with 10 votes.

There are almost 70 followers, but only 9 good questions, and only 20 questions total. We need more people to go and write down some questions they'd like to see on such a site. Noone will answer it, and you never have to come back to area51; it's just so that people can vote on what kind of question they think should belong.

I raised this issue on mathoverflow; many people supported my post, but only 1 person wrote 1 question.

So,

> Please, if you can think of any good math modelling/applied math questions that don't belong on physics or scicomp stackexchange, go to (http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/57490/mathematical-modeling) and write them down.

If you don't want to go to area51 because of time issues or xenophobia, please write some questions in the comments to this post, and someone else will copy them to area51 for you (hopefully).